# jQuery - masonry layout issues

Tags: jquery, layout, jquery-plugins, jquery-masonry

First time using jquery and im trying to get the basic masonry style to work, i've got the following code in my html...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<head>

<title>_Box</title>

<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<body>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="masonry.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).ready(function() {
    $("#container").masonry({
          itemSelector: '.item',
          columnWidth: 240,
          isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions
        });
});
</script>

<div id="container">

<div class="item"><img src="images/eventbox.png"></img></div>
<div class="item"><img src="images/forumbox.png"></img></div>
<div class="item"><img src="images/weekbox.png"></img></div>
<div class="item"><img src="images/weekbox.png"></img></div>
<div class="item"><img src="images/weekbox.png"></img></div>
<div class="item"><img src="images/weekbox.png"></img></div>
<div class="item"><img src="images/top10box.png"></img></div>
<div class="item"><img src="images/eventbox.png"></img></div>

</div>

</body>
</head>
```

and the following in my css file...

```
html {
  height:100%;
}

body {
  width:950px;
  height:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:100px;
  background-image: url(images/gridbg.png);
}

.item{
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

any help would be great as ive pretty much followed the tutorial yet its not working

this is what it looks like

http://i47.tinypic.com/2jfdr7n.jpg

if it helps, the images are different widths and height.

Question: How do i get the layout to what masonry is supposed to do, that being flow into one another nicely; examples on masonry site.

Comment: You should end the <head> element before the body. Other than that your code looks good to me. Have you checked the network tab and console? Maybe there is an error or you get a 404 on your masonry.js

Comment: Network is fine, console has said there is a syntax error in masonry - Object has no method 'masonry', believe it is this section $("#container") .masonry({ --- any ideas?

Comment: have you done what Xeano suggested and fix your invalid HTML?

Comment: Yes the HTML has been fixed although its stil not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the jQuery Masonry example, it has additional CSS defined for the wrappers.

Have you tried different CSS definitions? It might be looking for height and width properties to get the measurements of the objects on the page.

I would also suggest checking your implementation with a document ready and not window like what you have: 
`$(window).ready(function() {` >>> `$(document).ready(function() {`

Check out the source from the Masonry site. It's definitely different than what you have here and then use firebug or something similar to debug.

```
    var $items = $( items.join('') );
    $items.imagesLoaded(function(){
      $container
        .masonry( 'remove', $loadingItem ).masonry()
        .append( $items ).masonry( 'appended', $items, true );
    });
```